# How to fix "MySQLdb" package,the error:"Cannot create temporary build directory" on PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, mysql-python

I need to use `MySQLdb` package but there is an error saying `Cannot create temporary build directory` so I can't install it. How to fix this error?

I tried to change my working directory, or to delete the `.idea` file from the working directory where the script exits. Even more, I tried to install the package from the `cmd` but still have this error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb' more details the error
is ""Cannot create temporary build directory"
```

I have installed many packages and used them on `PyCharm` but can't fix the error with this one

Comment: do you use Linux? Did you try to install it with admin privillages ? Do have installed  mysql-server, mysqlclient, libmysql (there are not Python modules)

Comment: no I am using windows